# What reasons does Christianity give for "Why There Must Be A God?"

Tags: apologetics, philosophy, existence-of-god

I realize this question could also be addressed on [Philosophy.SE](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com), but I am very interested to get specifically the Christian perspective on this issue.

I was raised Catholic, but have left the Church in the last few years because of conflicts between my beliefs and the Church's. My lack of belief has definitely negatively affected my relationships with my family and I would really like a reason to believe once more. I suppose my real problem is that I have a hard time seeing a scenario, given what we have learned about the universe, that requires God to exist.

The question I would like to pose is, "**According to Christianity, why must there be a God?**"

Comment: The lack of reasons why there *must* be a God does not in any way reflect on whether there *is* a God.  Furthermore, it is quite valid to believe a thing, even though there is no proof requiring the thing.  You do it all the time - I assure you.  For example, most computer scientists believe that NP-Complete problems are not solvable in polynomial time.  However, there is no formal proof as of yet to this effect.  This neither stops us from looking for a proof, nor from believing that it is probably true, regardless of provability.

Comment: @Eric indeed, but usually people base critically-reasoned decisions on either: observable evidence (direct or indirect) for a "thing", or a well-reasoned logical demonstration of the *requirement* of a "thing" in the absence of evidence (consider the Higgs Boson until very recently). A huge question for many believers-with-doubts, and outright disbelievers is: does this god actually exist? why should I believe that? what reason would I have to accept this supernatural tale as true?

Comment: @degausser - painful as it is, your families issues with your non-belief have very little to do with whether you should believe - that should be based on whether you find evidence or reason on your own.

Comment: It is better for you to believe in God who rules the universe (and keeps it in perfect order) than NOT believing. When you believe in God, you turn out to be a good human. If you believe there is no God but in the end there turns out to be One on the Day, you will loose. However if you believe there IS a God, you are not loosing anything at all, so it is better to believe (with no cost) than to not believe (at the possible cost of punishment).

Comment: This question has undergone some revisions to highlight the focus on seeking for _Christian responses_. See [this meta thread](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1244/30) for more discussion behind this.

Comment: @Sarfraz. (a) Pascal's wager is fundamentally ridiculous. (b) Believing in God is not in any way correlated with being "a good human". (In fact, there's some amount of evidence for the opposite, but I wouldn't like to imply there's any causal effect there.)

Comment: There's an additional problem with Pascal's wager. Suppose a person A says: life is finite, believe in my God or else suffer an infinitely long hell. Then person B comes along and says: person A's hell is countably infinite; believe in my God, or else be thrown into a uncountably infinite hell!. then person C comes along and says: believe in my God, or else be thrown into a 2^{2^{R}}-infinite hell. ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are several classical arguments for believing in God, including:

The **cosmological argument**, which says that (logically) everything exists because it is caused by something else or because it has always existed. It says that everything that has been caused by something else must be caused by something else and so on until you get to something that is without cause. A thing without cause must always have existed. The first cause is God.

The **teleological argument** argues that the universe looks as if it has a design and a purpose. It argues that this is because it has a designer who gave it a purpose. It asks for a reason for the order in the universe, for natural laws and principles, and finds an explanation in God.

The **ontological argument** argues that God must exist if you can imagine that He exists... I'm not sure why, to be honest.

The **moral argument** says that naturalistic explanations of morality, love etc. are inadequate to explain the existence of morality, love etc.

Each of these arguments has received considerable attention by philosophers and theologians, with counter-arguments and counter-counter arguments having been debated for centuries. At the very least, however, some version of these arguments may remove intellectual barriers to faith and position you to accept the possibility that God is real.

Of course, even if you accept the veracity of one of these arguments, the God in its conclusion isn't necessarily the God of Christianity. Nevertheless, the conclusion of these arguments does appear to be compatible with Christianity. Moreover, some writers suggest that the cumulative effect of the arguments is to validate the Christian world-view.

For most Christians, rational argument is only a part of why we believe. Instead, we choose Jesus on the basis of religious experience or because he fills an emotional or pragmatic need. In my view, nobody can be **certain** of God's existence (or non-existence), but you can look at the balance of probabilities. As such, we each have to take responsibility to look at the arguments in the light of our experience and then decide for ourselves what to believe.

Comment: +1 for presenting the several common arguments with neutral detachment.

Comment: This answer has good structure but does not summarize any of the four basic types of argument particularly well.

Comment: To be more helpful: the cosmological argument is more subtle than the summary presented here, the teleological argument is more solid, and the answer doesn't even attempt to explain the ontological argument.

Answer (score 16):

**Logical Existence of God**

There is a very cogent line of reasoning presented in the book, *I don't have enough faith to be an atheist*, that goes something like this.

1. The physical universe consists of time, space, and matter.
2. Science has proven that the universe had a beginning--the Big Bang.
3. Nothing can create itself.
4. Whatever caused the universe to begin had to exist outside the universe of time, space, and matter.
5. This Creator is God.

Incidentally, the God who reveals Himself in the Bible is:

1. Outside of time--eternal
2. Outside of space--omnipresent
3. Outside of matter--spiritual

Comment: Ok, I guess my problem here is that the space between 4 and 5 is quite a jump for me. It seems like, in this explanation, God is just a place-holder for our lack of knowledge. Is it not possible that the process that started our universe was not God?

Comment: @degausser I highly recommend the book I mentioned.  It is a very reasoned and logical approach that goes into much greater detail of why the creative force must be personal and other things like that.  An impersonal force, if it created personal beings, would be creating something greater than itself.  This is impossible.

Comment: @degausser Briefly, no. A process is by itself meaningless without entities on which to act. For instance, without the existence somewhere in the universe (even if it's only cognitive) of legal input for an algorithm, then algorithm does not exist because by definition because the algorithm is defined by the work it is doing. Thus, you can question the causality premise of the argument, but accepting causality, you cannot reject the cause as having the qualities of God. Once you establish this, the entity with the qualities of God is assigned the name "God."

Comment: Defense of this entity being the Christian God is much more involved.

Comment: @Narnian To paraphrase Carl Sagan, why not "save a step" and declare the universe has always existed and is thus uncreated.  The big bang may be an intermediate step; not necessarily a beginning.

Comment: **Moderator Note:** Please reserve the comment function for items directly relating to improving the post in question. Discussions should be taken to [chat] _before_ they turn into ongoing dialogs on the issue itself.

Comment: -1 For not covering only one possible line of reasoning (used by some Christians) without addressing how Christianity has historically and does currently address this question.

Comment: What requires the entity described in step 4 to be God (step 5)? It seems like any entity capable of existing outside of space-time as we know it, and capable of creating things inside space-time as we know it meets the definition, and the added attributes generally ascribed to God are missing (loving, powerful, sentient, etc.). I feel like you're missing a step and it would be nice if you could elaborate, since the space between step 4 and 5 is really the most interesting part of this question.

Comment: @BrendanLong More specifically, that Creator is the God who reveals Himself in the Bible.  I agree that this is a big step.  To prove that beyond, not an *unreasonable* doubt, but a *reasonable* one requires looking at a lot of different things, for which space did not permit.  I highly recommend the book *I Don't Have Enough Faith to be an Atheist*.  This book takes a very logical approach, moving from why there is a Creator to why this Creator is the God of the Bible.

Comment: @Narnian Is it possible to put a small overview of these things? Most non-believers would just replace step 5 with "This creator is not God", so understanding why that would not be a valid conclusion is the most important part of the argument. I think expecting Stack Exchange readers to read an entire book to get an answer is generally not in the spirit of the site if there's an alternative.

Answer (score 11):

St. Thomas Aquinas outlines [five ways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinque_viae) of knowing, from reason alone, that God exists. These are tough to understand without a background in classical philosophy -- it's commonly assumed, for example, that the first and second ways (Unmoved Mover and First Cause) depend on demonstrating the absurdity of an infinite series reaching back **in time.** But properly understood the arguments have nothing to do with time.

Richard Dawkins famously dismissed the first three of the five ways as "essentially the same" in *The God Delusion*, which is, understood charitably, a bit of a misreading of Aquinas.

My 2nd-year theology class in [college](http://thomasaquinas.edu/) spent ten weeks discussing and arguing about the five ways (which all told would take up a couple of pages in a standard textbook), and I felt like we had barely scratched the surface.

I'm just now starting to read Edward Feser's *[Aquinas: A Beginner's Guide](http://books.google.com/books/about/Aquinas.html?id=uWdCAQAAIAAJ)* -- which has a great reputation and is apparently exactly what its title suggests: A user-friendly introduction to the thought of St. Thomas. Among other things it includes a discussion of and defense of the Five Ways (chapter 3, I guess).

Comment: Except that the question isn't answered...

Comment: And yet, the whole argument still fails, like countless others, in demonstrating that this God is in fact the Christian one.

Comment: @quantumSoup Per the moderator comment above, I'd be happy to take up the question in chat. Won't be able to comment frequently because of other commitments but that's probably just as well for a topic like this (not like it's going away any time soon!).

Comment: @SigueSigueBen, the question is "why must there be a God?". I linked to five classic answers to the question, tried to clear up some rudimentary misunderstandings of those answers, and pointed to a contemporary reference for diving deeper. How does that fail to answer the question?

Comment: @BenDunlap http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4350/chat-with-dunlap

Answer (score 4):

I totally understand your situation.

The best argument for me is "First Cause":  [The First Cause Argument.](http://www.existence-of-god.com/first-cause-argument.html)

As a scientifically minded person, arguments from Design tend to fall very short, unless you're talking at the cosmological scale, ie. the "fine tuning" of the various constants that allow the universe to exist at all and for us to have evolved to observe it.

I've also read some about Natural Law, and it has helped me to see God in a different light than the caricature from childhood stories.

Comment: @degausser:  it also helps me to think of God not as the stuff "before", "outside of", or "in between" the things that exist, but as _existence itself_

Answer (score 3):

I have never thought about it much because no other explanation seems to answer my basic questions. My basic question is why am I here, why do I sin and do I have to die? This led me to God years ago.

For basic beliefs in God I think that ’eternity’ can be sensed in space, sky. Also the beauty of nature speaks of someone else bigger than us. Most people throughout history have always believed in a God, or at least gods, simply from this basic observation. Therefore we can say all mankind generally believes in God because of what they see in nature and no other theory has been able to make them disbelieve what seems obvious.

**There is no need for a detailed philosophical argument as though it was not clear and plain by itself.**

In fact the Bible insults anyone's state of mind when they do not believe in God.

> The fool says in his heart, "There is no God."  (NIV Psalms 14:1)

This is not meant to insult you. I share it as encouragement to help you avoid a need of a clever argument. **Just believe what you already know in you heart and take your doubts to God.** He is in the business of removing doubts when you seek Him. Reading the Bible yourself will help you in this a lot. I would start with the gospels, Mathew, Mark, Luke or John.

Comment: As a point of logic: that quote does not imply that all who say that "there is no God" are fools, but that (all) who are fools say that "there is no God."

Comment: @IgnatiusTheophorus unless you are translating from the original source, I suspect it could be ambiguous which way the association is. For example, is it "it is a fool who say in his heart...".

Comment: "There is no need for a detailed philosophical argument as though it was not clear and plain by itself." yes, there very much is. Things that are "clear and plain" are not necessarily correct. It was considered "clear and plain" that the sun and moon went around the earth, for example. Frankly, I consider that this completely fails to address the question. "meh, it must be" is not an argument for the existence of God.

Comment: @MarcGravell - I do not mean to be insulting, I truly just can't comprehend atheism and think an atheist knows in his own heart that their is a God and there is no argument that will persuade him otherwise.  I think an atheist can believe in God by simply choosing to do so and no longer resisting the evidence God has provide in his own conscience and heart. It is not a very god answer from the rational standpoint, I agree, but that does not mean it is not true. If I said I do not exist would it be logical to argue that I do, or simply say that I should as I must know it is true?

Comment: @Mike it doesn't matter whether you comprehend it or not; please hear me: every part of my heart, brain, and every other part of my body says "nope, absolutely no evidence or reason for that; it is just hopeful superstition". It isn't a case of resisting the evidence; there is exactly zero to resist. Your last point is silly: based on our admittedly limited perception, one's own existence is apparent. That does not extend to invisible, undetectable, inactive agents. The simpler answer to that is: it doesn't exist: it is a myth: a legend: an accident of tenacious story-telling.

Comment: @MarcGravell - I understand your point, I just do not agree. It is the bible that say's 'the fool' says this in his heart, not me. The Bible does not try to argue for the existence of God it just declares it to be so.  I find nothing unreasonable with the Bible on that stance. God is the only subject that has authority in the conscience. This means it has to be declared and preached because we all know it's true. Just as some do not admit there is a God, I do not beleive atheists truly exist.  Atheist's use the mind God gave them to deny His presence surrounding them.  This is foolish.

Comment: "because we all know it's true" is invalid; "I do not beleive atheists truly exist": no, they really really do; "admit" - the word you are looking for is "accept" or "believe"

Comment: @MarcGravell - bravo, we have established that we do not agree. The next step is to agree to disagree. I appreciate your honesty and respect your view. It helps identify the different view that I think the Bible has and are good constructive comments. Cheers.

Comment: **Moderator note:** (_cleared large number of comments_) Please take conversations about the issue and between each-other to [chat] and reserve the comment space for direct feeback on individual posts.

Answer (score 3):

Not all Christians claim that there is a reason for "There must be a God"

Quoting Tozer:

> Faith never goes contrary to reason; faith simply ignores reason and rises above it.
>   Reason could not tell us that Jesus Christ should be born of the Virgin Mary, but faith knows he was. Reason cannot prove that jesus took upon Him the form of a man and died under the sins of the world, but faith knows that He did. Reason can not prove that the third day He rose from the dead, but faith knows that He did. Faith is an organ of knowledge.
>
> Fundamental rationalists say the human brain alone is an organ of knowledge. They forget there are at lest two other organs of knowledge. Feeling is an organ of knowledge, too. All the reasoning in the world couldn't tell you the temperature was 90 today. You felt that it was. I can stand heat like a lizard, but I've had enough of this. And I know it was hot today. I had an organ of knowledge today - feeling.
>
> A young man loves a young woman. How does he know it? Does he read the Encyclopedia Britannica and apply reason to it? No. He listens to the ticking of his own heart. He knows it by feeling. Feeling is an organ of knowledge. reason is an organ of knowledge and faith is an organ of knowledge. And we have to believe that.
>
> Reason can not say, "Jesus rose from the dead." Faith knows He did. Reason cannot say, "He sits at the right hand of God Father Almighty." Reason doesn't know, but faith knows that he did. Reason cannot say, "He shall come to judge the quick and the dead." But faith knows that He will come. Reason cannot say, "My sins are all gone." But faith knows they're gone. So, all down the line, faith is an organ of knowledge. ...

Comment: Good answer in terms of how it relates to the question. As an idle observation (not a critique of the answer, as the words are not yours), The "fundamental rationalist" would respond that feeling and faith are functions of the brain, along with knowledge; not separate organs parallel-to and equal-with the brain, and that (thinking of the temperature example) the "knowledge" here is merely recollection of sensory inputs and nervous responses earlier in that day.

Comment: @Marc: I don't quite buy the "temperature" example either. As technically, we can use thermometers to measure the temperature. However, I do buy the "falling in love" example and the "Jesus rose from the dead" example. I don't know how to measure either of those exactly.

Comment: adrenaline, dopamine, seratonin, oxytocin, vasopressin, ...

Comment: I think that's infatuation and excitement. Do old married copies still have such chemical responses?

Comment: I genuinely do not know

Answer (score 1):

I find it interesting among all the answers given that the issue of spoken and answered prophecy has not been raised. In the bible, God gives us sneak previews of the coming Messiah so that when He comes we may recognize Him. Such lists of OT texts fulfilled in the NT are populated all over the 'net. To have even just 25 of those prophecies come true in one person is remarkable.

God specifically used prophecy, foretelling the future with accuracy, to distinguish Himself from Israel's idols, which had mouths, but could not speak ([Isaiah 48:3-5](https://www.blueletterbible.org/esv/isa/48/3/s_727003)). There must be a God, for no other being could predict the coming of this person with remarkable details spread over hundreds of years and through various authors in various cultures and still keep the focus on this coming Messiah.

Answer (score 0):

God is there not to prove his presence for us. It is we, who have to seek and know Him and then He Makes Himself known to us. It is we, who have to make efforts to seek him and understand his presence in our daily life ad not vice versa. If we pretend to be blind for whatever he has done in this universe and to us then it is our problem and not God’s. He is always there to make Himself known to us and what is required is our will to acknowledge his presence out there.

Take a real life example of boarding a plane to travel to a distant city. How we are sure that we will reach there safely and at that designated arrival time.  Some one will say that I know nothing would happen because the ground staff would take care of everything and carry out all the pre flight checks to ensure that everything is fine for the plane to take off/land.

However, how we can be content that these technicians did their job flawlessly. We have no way of checking it nor has time to do it every time we board a plane. We only ‘believe’ that they have done their job correctly, would also ‘hope’ so and also ‘trust’ in their ability in doing it precisely and also keep ‘faith’ in their sincerity so that they have not missed deliberately any critical checks and also know that it is their duty to do it diligently etc etc.

With all these assumptions but with no concrete way of verifying it our self, we relax in our seat with an assurance that we will reach our destination safely at the predetermined time.  That is exactly the way religious people believe in God. However, unlike these ground technicians, the only difference is that innumerable people experience God when they have proper relationship with Him and this happens with only the chosen few and the rest of us at least have to believe these chosen few for assuring the presence of God.

Atheist put forth argument that the universe is in place and the it is there so, in that orderly manner owing to physical laws but fail to explain how these laws came into existence. We need to understand that Creation of universe by God is akin to developing a computer or a computer programme step by step and running it to get the desired results. Scientists and programmers are doing exactly the same for a PC to get the desired results. Ultimately, what layperson understands is that it is the PC that has given the desired output, when in fact the real architect is the programmer or the maker of PC. That is what happened when universe was formed. God programmed all these laws and left them to do the rest, the way HE desired including the “evolution” if it is there.

In Genesis it says that the land was initially a huge single mass.  Even scientists say that it was a deformed earth earlier and after the movement of the land mass, it took the shape as it is now. Some places where it went too high, it became hills and mountains. It is a known fact that Indian sub continent was earlier touching  Australia and after slow movement(drifting) of land mass, which still continues to happen even today, it got separated and that’s how Himalaya is also formed. Initially when God created land, he probable was instrumental in accelerating it at much faster rate as He was the author of everything.  It is like making a PC to run as you want by developing a suitable programme to get the desired result. Only the inventor of a PC would know how to make it work the way he desire and then leave it to the PC to do it s work on its own.

Answer (score -3):

It is better for you to believe in God who rules the universe (and keeps it in perfect order) than NOT believing. When you believe in God, you turn out to be a good human. If you believe there is no God but in the end there turns out to be One on the Day, you will loose. However if you believe there IS a God, you are not loosing anything at all, so **it is better to believe (with no cost) than to not believe (at the possible cost of punishment).**

Human has limited senses to perceive each and everything in this universe. There are certain things you don't feel but have to believe in. Not believing in God because you don't feel or perceive Him sounds absurd, you can't prove He doesn't exit to those who believe. You need to explore the nature, working of a cell to anything, you would notice complete order in everything.

Human nature calls for help automatically when in troubles and adversities which itself is a proof that there is One, the Creator.

Comment: Hey @Swrfraz and welcome to Christianity.SE. I appreciate your participation in the site and would encourage you to continue, however I need to emphisis that when it comes to answers, we are looking for things that represent Christian doctrine. This answer does not. The line of reasoning here is common among philosophers both inside and outside of Christian circles and is often held by nominal professing Christians, but at its core anybody that understands the teachings of Christianity would agree that it is contrary to the Christian faith.

Answer (score -4):

Universe without a Creator?  It is a simple impossibility.  If so then why so much of order and so much of compatibility.  I have already said about order existing in the universe in my earlier answer. Now a little probing about the compatibility. It is impossible to get compatibility in the living things by the process so much hyped by atheist and called evolution.

Assuming for the sake of argument that evolution is tenable, then   the least we can accept that a evolution can do is to evolve a creature to a better creature,  but not create a compatible mating creature to it. **My question is, how the existence of male and female in every type of creatures came into being through evolution.** A male cannot evolve into female over the years. What a fallacy to believe that it happened through evolution? Take the simple case of organs for reproduction. They are exactly compatible to each other. How this can happen through evolution? Unless there is some external force who made this happen and the other intricacies in them, which I would not like to dissect further here.  There are so many other things which are both unique as well as compatible between male and female and unless there is a master designer this would be impossible to imagine that it happened through evolution.

You can understand God and know Him only through faith and not by human reasoning. If that was the case then He would be just like a creature not Creator...Think of Stephan Hawkings.. such a genius..Possibly this is God's way of preventing humans from knowing too much about Him.

The posts that I see which are against existence of God appears to be from well informed people and from those who have mastered science.  Be it known that there are many renowned scientist who have done deep research in many fields of science and yet they are still believers in a Creator. With miniscule knowledge of science and relying on the books from authors who in way have any scientific background to their repute can be dangerous. They are only misleading by ignorance of not having complete knowledge of science. I am sure none of those who have posted these answers, have actually witnessed any of the experiments that these scientist claimed to have proved and I would not expect them to do so. Yet they believe what is told to them just because it is recorded lately and not 2000 years back. You know what I mean.

One thing that I found, out of place in a para of quantumSoup is “why not follow teachings of Muhammad?  This looks like firing from shoulder of foe in arms. Why to follow the teaching of Mohammad?  @Shredder has already clarified in his comment and I would append that the message that is emanating from his preaching is diametrically opposite to that of Jesus. Sporadic preaching about indulging in violence and participating in that violence towards some refusing to follow him and his ultimate death completely contrasts to Jesus who preached love and only love to the extent of loving your enemy and practiced these teaching in his lifetime. This too, leaving aside his Divinty which is a different topic. He even mingled with sinners to make them change their lives and to bring them on right path...and death could not over power him but was raised to life after death. Draw your conclusion from this.

Comment: "A male cannot evolve into female over the years. What a fallacy to believe that it happened through evolution?" actually, there are many species that can change **inside a single lifetime**. Sorry, but I believe this answer is ignorant of a lot of basic fundamental knowledge of biology and evolution. Re " just because it is recorded lately" - no, because it has been strongly supported by repeatable evidence, thoroughly peer reviewed. You can *retest* this stuff. Science isn't just what a person says to be true.

Comment: [There are scientific theories on the evolution of sexual reproduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolution_of_sexual_reproduction), just because you can't think of a way it might have happened doesn't mean it is impossible. And your remark about Hawking is tasteless and disgusting, I recommmend you remove that entirely.

Comment: @mad Scientist ..My apologies ..removed it. By the way you said theories not proof or experiments..

Comment: -1 This post is riddled with misconceptions about evolution and belies a lack of understanding of what a scientific theory is. It's not a hunch or a guess. A theory explains how things work the way they do given the existing evidence and have been shown to be correct time and again. Gravitational theory explains why objects fall when dropped. Feel free to jump off a cliff if you believe theories are just speculation. In fact, we probably have more evidence supporting the theory of evolution than gravity.

Comment: All these comments from Atheist portrays one truth which is so glaringly noticeable...they try to defend which they can't understand with their unscientific mind but rely in faith on scientists on what they found in their research which is not convincing or conclusive at all. There are things, conclusively proved by scientist, but “Evolution” is far from it and it is just a gimmick of atheist, a wall sort of, to lean on something to belittle the theist, nothing more than that. . .  All this has revealed nothing more than futility in their pursuit to prove theist wrong.

Comment: @Joao. Proudly waving your own ignorance around as a banner is not a good way to win friends and influence people.

Comment: @TRiG The knowledge you pretend you have is termed as foolishness by billions of people who are not like you.

Comment: @JoaoRodrigues. Critiquing a position you don't understand, and are proud to not understand, is not going to make you look good. Wilful ignorance is never an attractive character trait.

Comment: @TRiG  I am happy to say that you only endorse my assesment in above comment. Friend, do you have an understanding to realise that this same logic applies to you and your position of belief too?

Comment: @JoaoRodrigues. I don't recall ever saying or doing anything to suggest I was proud of my own ignorance. In fact, I find religion fascinating, though I don't believe it, and am eager to learn about it. Your complete misunderstanding of biology, and utter lack of intellectual curiosity on the subject, is very different.